# How many "outer joins" can a table have?

Tags: sql, outer-join

Everything is in the title: if I do a select query across several tables, how many `outer joins` can I use? As many tables there are?

Comment: Any number, there's no limit.

Comment: Nipicking: a table never has an "outer join" - a query has.

Comment: @jarlh: that's not entirely true. MySQL for example has a limit of 61 tables - whether it that is a real limitation or a theoretical one is a different question though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "Tables per SELECT statement": [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.130).aspx)

- For SQL Server 2008 & up the maximum is only limited by available resources.
- For SQL Server 2005 there was a 256 table limit.

Comment: And I even know of a case where someone in the company I worked for hit that limit by using nested views. Sadly at least half the joins were to the same table! What mess that was to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the DBMS limit will be higher than you should ever need.  There is a common sense limit in terms of how many joins to use for effective querying.  This needs to be part of your over all design consideration ( your app, your db schema \ indexing, etc. )

Comment: That's not true. Various DBMS impose limits, for example [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) supports up to 64 tables and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/joins-limits.html) only 61 tables i na single join.

Comment: Did not know that.  If you ever need that many joins, you have definitely missed something in your design.